# Symfony - Doctrine : Could not resolve type of column "MENUSid" of class "App\Entity\Menus"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting this error : Could not resolve type of column "MENUSid" of class "App\Entity\Menus"

I'm trying to have a OneToMany relation between two entities : MENUS and FORMULA => there is many formulas for one Menu

Thanks for your help

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use App\Repository\MenusRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MenusRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "MENUS")]

class Menus
{
    #[ORM\Id()]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "AUTO")]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private $MENUSid;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", nullable: false)]
    private ?string $MENUSname;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Formula::class, mappedBy: 'FORMULAmenu')]
    private $MENUSformulas;
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity()]
#[ORM\Table(name: "FORMULA")]

class Formula
{
    #[ORM\Id()]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "AUTO")]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    private ?int $FORMULAid;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "float", nullable: false)]
    private ?float $FORMULAprice;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", nullable: true)]
    private ?string $FORMULAdescription;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer", nullable: true)]
    private $FORMULAmenuId;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Menus::class, inversedBy: 'MENUSformulas')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name:"FORMULAmenuId", referencedColumnName:"MENUSid")]
    private $FORMULAmenu;
```

Comment: Check your db for the actual name, are you sure it is not just `id`? Here `referencedColumnName:"MENUSid"`.  You should try and use the [maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship) to create your relations as this will do everything for you.

Comment: The Doctrine ORM hides the details of linking tables and such.  You are still think in terms of $ids and tables instead of objects and entities.  Basically you should have a Formula::menu property as opposed to Formula::FORMULAmenuId.  Technically either would work but it is a conceptual thing.  Take the time to read the basics in the docs and work through an example or two.  And yes, `make:entity` can be your friend while getting started.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I understood the error, it was an uppercase difference with my db name